# Set only the bias to be non-trainable in TensorFlow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When training Neural Networks for classification in TensorFlow/Keras, is it possible to set the bias term in the output layer to non-trainable?

It looks like `layer.trainable = False` will freeze both the kernel and the bias in this layer. Is it possible to only freeze the bias, but still update the kernel?

Answer (score 2):

A hacky solution with initializers and constraints for uninitialized models.

If your model has been initialized, you will need to replace the layers in order to add initializers and constraints. See https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13100.

#### Biases with different values

```py
class ConstantTensorInitializer(tf.keras.initializers.Initializer):
  """Initializes tensors to `t`."""

  def __init__(self, t):
    self.t = t

  def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None):
    return self.t

  def get_config(self):
    return {'t': self.t}

class ConstantTensorConstraint(tf.keras.constraints.Constraint):
  """Constrains tensors to `t`."""

  def __init__(self, t):
    self.t = t

  def __call__(self, w):
    return self.t

  def get_config(self):
    return {'t': self.t}


#Example
biases = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
layer = Conv2D(
  4,
  (3, 3),
  use_bias=True,
  bias_initializer=ConstantTensorInitializer(biases),
  bias_constraint=ConstantTensorConstraint(biases)
)
```

#### Biases with the same value

```py
class ConstantValueConstraint(tf.keras.constraints.Constraint):
  """Constrains the elements of the tensor to `value`."""

  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  def __call__(self, w):
    return w * 0 + self.value

  def get_config(self):
    return {'value': self.value}


#Example
layer = Conv2D(
  4,
  (3, 3),
  use_bias=True,
  bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(0.1), 
  bias_constraint=ConstantValueConstraint(0.1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set use_bias to false for any layer.

ie.

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), use_bias=False))
```

Comment: Thanks! But does this mean there will be no bias term? I would like to fix the bias to some given value, for example, bias b = 0.1 during the entire training process.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do but yes, you can put a weights/bias constraint which will be called after every gradient update and you can modify the values for weights or constraints   check https://keras.io/api/layers/constraints/

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the confusion. What I want to do is the following: suppose we do `layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, kernel_initializer=w0, bias_initializer=b0)` and `layer.trainable = False` , Then during the entire `model.fit` process, both the kernel and bias will not be updated, so we always have `kernel == w0, bias==b0` for this layer, right? Now, is it possible to only keep `bias=b0`, but still update the kernel?